# Azure Container Instances: Create a multi-container group from Django+Nginx+Postgres

Tags: django, azure, docker, nginx, azure-container-instances

I have dockerized a Django project with Postgres, Gunicorn, and Nginx following  [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/).

Now i want to move the application to azure container instances. Can i simply create a container group following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-yaml), and expect the container images to communicate the right way?

To run the project locally i use `docker-compose -f docker-**compose.prod.yml** up -d --build` But how is the communication between the containers handled in azure container instances?

The docker-compose.prod.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
        - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
        - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
        - 8000
    env_file:
        - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
        - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
        - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
        - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
        - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
        - 1337:80
    depends_on:
        - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The containers will be able to communicate with each others using the services names (web, db, nginx) because they are part of the container group's local network.  Also, take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-yaml) as you can't use docker-composes file directly [unless you use the edge version of Docker Desktop](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deploy-to-azure-container-instances-with-docker-desktop/).

On another note, upon restarting, you will loose whatever you stored in your volumes because you are not using some kind of external storage. Look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files).